Resolution of Einstein prediction of brightness loss with acceleration
Stars moving at velocities relative to us nearer to light speed are predicted to have lower brightness as well as red shift.  Brightness loss has not been observed, however.  Could this be due to changes in the fusion reaction inside the stars?  The same Lorentzian transformation should be happening on the nuclear level, after all.

I am not familiar with this prediction of brightness loss. Where did you read about it?

There's red (and blue) shift,  but there's also relativistic beaming. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_beaming
